# iPhone HTTP video streaming: How to show still image when playing audio-only stream

Tags: iphone, ipad, video-streaming, avplayer, http-streaming

I have an iPad app playing http video streaming using variant playlist, which have multi streams with different bit rate for different bandwidths. One of then is audio only stream for lowest bandwidth. The app use **AVPlayer** to play the video. For some reason, I can't use MPMoviePlayerViewController.

The problem I have is that when the video player play **audio-only stream** the video display black screen, the audio still playing. Which I think is awful to users, they don't know what going on. I want to display a still image in place of the video player. like  this

[image: Standard iPad Video Player - Playing Audio Stream only]

Is there any way I can detect when the player switch to different stream? Or detect if the stream is audio-only?

Comment: With "For some reason, I can't use MPMoviePlayerViewController.", do you mean a reason you don't know or a reason you do know and live with?

Comment: Well the main reason is I have to build custom video player.

Answer (score 3):

Since I encountered this issue and the previous answer is not complete (doesn't cover live stream case) - here is my improvement on top of it:

```
if ([keyPath isEqual:@"tracks"])
    {
        BOOL hasVideoTrack = NO;
        for (AVPlayerItemTrack* track in [[yourPlayer.currentItem] tracks]) 
        {                
            if ([track.assetTrack.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) 
            {
                 hasVideoTrack = YES;
                 break;
            }
        }
        if (hasVideoTrack)
        {
           // Remove audio only view
        } else {
           // Show audio only view
        }
    }
```

Do note - this however will only let you show a local Audio only screen.
When playing a live stream - the Artwork for the audio only is supposed to come from the stream, so my code is more towards this:

```
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"] == YES){
for (AVMetadataItem *metadata in self.player.currentItem.timedMetadata) {
    if ([[metadata commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
        UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:metadata.dataValue];
        UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImage];
        overlayImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        // If an audio only slide is already there, make it disappear.
        [self hideAudioOnlySlide];

        self.audioOnlyView = overlayImageView;
        [self showAudioOnlySlide];
        self.audioOnlyView.size = _playerView.size;
        break;
    }
}


}else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"tracks"] == YES){
    NSArray *tracks = self.player.currentItem.tracks;            
    if ([self.player.currentItem hasVideoTracks] == NO) {
        // Check if there is timed metadata with artwork that indicates audio only is handled at the stream level.
        BOOL hasAudioOnlyFromStream = NO;
        for (AVMetadataItem *metadata in self.player.currentItem.timedMetadata) {
            if ([[metadata commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
                hasAudioOnlyFromStream = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If we don't have audio only slide from the stream - carry on to show audio only slide.
        //Otherwise - this is handled by the timed metadata check for artwork.
        if (hasAudioOnlyFromStream == NO) {
            [self showAudioOnlySlide];
        }
    } else {
        [self hideAudioOnlySlide];
    }
}
```

Add observation code:

```
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:0 context:NULL];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Remove observation code:

```
@try {
    [item removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"];
    [item removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks"];
}
```

hasVideoTracks code (Inside a category over AVPlayerItem):

```
- (BOOL)hasVideoTracks{
    BOOL hasVideoTracks = NO;
    for (AVPlayerItemTrack* track in [self tracks]){
        if ([track.assetTrack.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
            hasVideoTracks = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    return hasVideoTracks;
}
```

Note:

1. DON'T use presentationSize to detect audio only - in iOS 7 it no longer becomes CGSizeZero when moving to audio only - but gives some funky sizes instead. It's not a reliable method.
2. Show/Hide audioOnlySlide is pretty straight forward and should contain your implementation.

Comment: I tried your code but I find hasVideoTracks = Yes , even when the http live stream plays only audio (video playback is stuck )

Comment: Interesting , what OS is that? My code was written for 7 and for sure it was properly working then. Maybe they messed this up again.
Also - are you trying a VOD or Live stream? Did you verify you have a properly encoded audio only stream ? (with or without a slide?)

Comment: I am running in iOS 8.4 , and I am trying Live Stream, can u pls tell me how to check encoded audio only stream property , and also I have created a question in stack overflow regarding this here http://stackoverflow.com/q/32123030/1730345 , can u pls help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you test it with link conditioner and waited over 10 - 20 seconds (2 segments time ...)
Can you add the m3u8's of both your main stream and audio only stream?
This solution works on 8.4 for my apps (> millions of users monthly)

Comment: I find avplayer plays both audio & video when the internet bandwidth is good , but when the network speed is low (I am throttling it using charles )it plays only the audio whereas video looks stuck.I want to know when this transition happen and how to capture this transition. Asset track always shows as it has video .  BTW I waited for 20 sec and checked the asset track (while only audio is playing) but it still shows AVMediaTypeVideo.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up observer for the tracks property in AVPlayerItem.

```
[yourPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks" options:0 context:nil];
```

Than you need to implement method that will be called every time when tracks will be changed

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"tracks"])
    {
        for (AVPlayerItemTrack* track in [[yourPlayer.currentItem] tracks]) 
        {
            if ([track.assetTrack.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeAudio]) 
            {
                 // Audio track available
            }
            if ([track.assetTrack.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) 
            {
                 // Video track available
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There some space for tuning up, take a look at [NSKeyValueObserving Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath%3aofObject%3achange%3acontext%3a) and [AVPlayerItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayerItem)

Comment: That's actually very clever. Let's me try this out. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Mastering Modern Media Playback (WWDC 2014):

```
AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem
Deciding when to show audio-only UI
// Inside -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: implementation...
if (presentationSizeObservationContext == context) {
    // Check if new presentation size is CGSizeZero.
    CGSize size = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey].sizeValue;
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)) {
       for (AVPlayerItemTrack *playerItemTrack in playerItem.tracks) {
          AVAssetTrack *track = playerItemTrack.assetTrack;
          if ([track hasMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicAudible]) {
              // Show audio-only UI.
          } 
       }
    }
}
```

Link: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#503

Comment: Where do you define the context on if statement?